# AngularJS unit test directory structure Best Practices

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

What is the best practice to follow to create the directory structure for unit tests when using AngularJS for e.g. in general following struct

As mentioned in the link https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure

What should be the structure to place the unit test files in...if it's an MVC Visual Studio project, should it be in the separate unit test project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Google Best practice](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) which has similar grouping by component you would have the tests in the same folder as the item under test. To keep the same naming convention you would name the tests like homeControllerTest.js or you could use homeController_test.js

Comment: I am kind of new to web development, we are using visual studio for development. wont it create issue when we bundle the pages for release.

Comment: Possibly. How are you bundling it? Are you using asp.net bundling? You can exclude files in your bundle? Also if you are packaging up your code using a CI server such as TeamCity you can exclude files from the deployable package

Comment: The idea in separating the structure by component is to keep everything for the component together including tests.

Comment: @shyam_ you can exclude the test folder in your build process. If you are using Grunt it makes more easier to exclude files/folders

Answer (score 5):

Putting them side-by-side with the file under test seems to be recommended.

For example:

```
folder/
  file.js
  file.spec.js
  otherfile.js
  otherfile.spec.js
```

This recommendation comes from a very good style guide found here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y197

Comment: file.js, file.spec.js, file.prot.spec.js,  file.po.js